# Struggling to get some basic JQuery and JS code working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the code below, when `menuLeft` has the class 'cbp-spmenu-open', it is displayed on screen. When it doesn't have that class, it is not on screen.

Im trying to make some code so that, when the menu is on screen, it will disappear when the user clicks on anything apart from the menu.

In my code below, Im basically trying to tell it:

If the menu is on the screen, clicking on anything but the webpage makes the menu disappear.

Not too sure where I have gone wrong, so if anyone could post some correct code that would be great! Thanks.

```
if ( $('.menuLeft').hasClass('cbp-spmenu-open') ) {
        $("*").not("#menuRight").click(function() {
        classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    });
}
```

EDIT:

```
var menuLeft = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s1' ),
        menuRight = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s2' ),
        menuTop = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s3' ),
        menuBottom = document.getElementById( 'cbp-spmenu-s4' ),
        // showLeft = document.getElementById( 'showLeft' ),
        showRight = document.getElementById( 'showRight' ),
        showTop = document.getElementById( 'showTop' ),
        showBottom = document.getElementById( 'showBottom' ),
        showLeftPush = document.getElementById( 'showLeftPush' ),
        showRightPush = document.getElementById( 'showRightPush' ),
        body = document.body;

        var showLeft=document.getElementsByClassName('showLeft');
        for(var i=0;i<showLeft.length;i++) {
            showLeft[i].onclick = function() {
            classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
            classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
            disableOther( 'showLeft' );
};

}

// showLeft.onclick = function() {
//  classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
//  classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
//  disableOther( 'showLeft' );
// };
showRight.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRight' );
};
showTop.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuTop, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showTop' );
};
showBottom.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuBottom, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showBottom' );
};
showLeftPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toright' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeftPush' );
};
showRightPush.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( body, 'cbp-spmenu-push-toleft' );
    classie.toggle( menuRight, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showRightPush' );
};

function disableOther( button ) {
    if( button !== 'showLeft' ) {
        classie.toggle( showLeft, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRight' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRight, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showTop' ) {
        classie.toggle( showTop, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showBottom' ) {
        classie.toggle( showBottom, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showLeftPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showLeftPush, 'disabled' );
    }
    if( button !== 'showRightPush' ) {
        classie.toggle( showRightPush, 'disabled' );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the outcome of your code?

Comment: If you mean in the console, it says 'ReferenceError: Can't find variable: showLeft'. The code itself doesn't have any impact on the page whatsoever.

Comment: If that is the error in the console, then you have at least one additional issue in your code, since `showLeft` isn't anywhere in the code that you've provided here.

Comment: I have edited my post with the other JS file added. I have also fixed the variable showLeft. New error is: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'showRight').

Comment: You can do much better than `$("*").not("#menuRight").click(function()` bind the click to document and check if it has a parent of the open class

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the cleanest solution but I think this will work for you with the least amount of work

Something like this:

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
    $('.menuRight').addClass('cbp-spmenu-close');
});

showRightMenu = function(e) {
    $('.menuRight').removeClass('cbp-spmenu-close');
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}

$(".menuRight").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lpbxxufd/7/